# Android build fails in new Android Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-bumblebee

Hello there guys i need some help from you, I have updated my Android Studio to Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3.
And after downloading Gradle 7.2 and installed it on my system, it was correct, I added it to the Gradle path in the studio. Now the problem comes here when building project at first time
Here is the Error am getting

```
Gradle sync failed: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
            - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
            - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.3')
            Searched in the following repositories:
            Gradle Central Plugin Repository
            Google
            MavenRepo (6 m 19 s 228 ms)
```